# Azure VM IP Address

Tags: azure, ip, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to run some VOIP software on my Azure VM, but it's picking up the internal IP address 10.x.x.x and broadcasting it to external servers. The external servers obviously can't see that internal address. So, I want to configure the machine such that its IP address is the static external address (13.x.x.x). When I run ipconfig, I need the IPv4 address to be my (13.x.x.x). This way the VOIP software will broadcast the correct externally accessible IP address.

What's the best way to do this in Azure? Do I just go to the server itself and turn off "obtain IP address automatically" and put in my static external IP or is there some other "Azure" way of doing what I'm trying to do? PS. I'm pretty new to Azure VMs and associated IT management.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what I ended up doing is:

- In the portal I added an address range and sub-net to the virtual network that included my external, static IP address
- In the portal I changed the sub-net that the VM network interface was using to the new one that included my external IP. I also set the address to "static" and put in external address
- Rebooted the VM

The VM now reports the internal address and external address as being the same external address which is what I wanted. Not sure if this is the best or only way to do this but it worked for me. Open to better recommendations if anyone has one.